# Changes to a batch file not working the way I would expect

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm working through the book Agile Java by Jeff Langr and have a batch file (run.bat) set up to compile and run my classes. I've just changed my file structure as more packages have been introduced, and feel like I understand the classpath, but one tweak I'm trying to make isn't working the way I would expect.

It all compiles and runs fine with the following batch file:

```
@echo off
javac -classpath C:\junit3.8.1.jar;C:\AgileJava\Lessons studentinfo\*.java reports\*.java
if not errorlevel 1 java -cp C:\junit3.8.1.jar;C:\AgileJava\Lessons junit.awtui.TestRunner sis.studentinfo.AllTests
```

I'm trying to make the last statement as follows (adding \sis to the classpath and removing the reference to sis from studentinfo.AllTests):

```
if not errorlevel 1 java -cp C:\junit3.8.1.jar;C:\AgileJava\Lessons\sis junit.awtui.TestRunner studentinfo.AllTests
```

But get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: studentinfo/AllTests (wrong name: sis/studentinfo/AllTests)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at junit.runner.TestCaseClassLoader.loadClass(TestCaseClassLoader.java:104)
        at junit.runner.ReloadingTestSuiteLoader.load(ReloadingTestSuiteLoader.java:9)
        at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.loadSuiteClass(BaseTestRunner.java:193)
        at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:86)
        at junit.awtui.TestRunner.runSuite(TestRunner.java:455)
        at junit.awtui.TestRunner.start(TestRunner.java:536)
        at junit.awtui.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:382)
```

Can anyone explain why? I get that it's because it's not finding the AllTests class but I can't see how else I would get it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing to the `junit.awtui.TestRunner` the name of a class, in which it should find some tests.

You need to pass the "fully qualified class name", which is the package that a class was declared in, followed by its class name. 
When you wrote your class `AllTests`, you specified which package it was in.  It looks like you specified that it was in `sis.studentinfo`, which means that the fully qualified name is `sis.studentinfo.AllTests`.  The name `studentinfo.AllTests` refers to a different class, which apparently doesn't exist.

Note that when you specify the classpath, you are just specifying which directories (and/or archives) java will look in for classes - it doesn't change how you refer to the class - the class names are not relative to the classpath.

Comment: Bingo - that really helps, thank you. You’re right, the package in AllTests is sis.studentinfo. Silly me